# Expressing pushforward of a flow in integral form

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $\phi(t,x)$ be a flow of a vectorfield $V$ on some compact domain $\tilde{U} = U\times I \in R^n \times R$. Let X be a vector field. If one wants to write

$(\phi(t,x))_{*}X)(\phi(t,x)(q)) = \phi(t,x))_*(X(q))$

in integral form, is there anything wrong in writing

$(\phi(t,x))_*(X(q)) = X(q) + \int_{0}^t DV_{\phi(x,s)}\circ D\phi(x,s)X(q) ds$

(this can be obtained either by direct derivation of $\phi(t,x))_{*}(X(q))$ or by finding an ODE satisfied by the flow $(\phi(t,x))_{*}X)(\phi(t,x)(q))$ using chronological calculus)

so in particular,

$|\phi(t,x))_*(X(q)) - X(q)| \sim t\sup|DV|\sup|D\phi||X|$

I am asking this because usually people dont express pushword in the integral form but they express it as a series

$\phi(t,x))_* = Id + t[V,.] + t^2[V,[V,.]]+...$

(which converges on a bounded subset of functions). Then continuing this analysis one can derive results where (see Agrachev - Control Theory from Geometric Viewpoint Chapter 2)

$|((\phi(t,x))_*-I)X| \sim e^{|DV|}|DX|$

The appearance of $|DX|$ in one analysis and $|X|$ in the other confuses me. Is there a problem in the first part? Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you consider $\lim_{t\to 0} (\phi(t)_*X - X) / t$, this should give you $[V,X]$ by the definition of the Lie derivative. But using your integral equation that is not what you get. So you made a mistake.

Comment: The ODE solved by the $\phi(t)_*X$ should be $$ \frac{d}{dt} \phi(t)_*X = [V,\phi(t)_* X] $$ by the definition of the flow. This will necessarily contain a term depending on the derivative of $X$.

Comment: And in chronological calculus notation the derivation goes like this $\phi \circ ((\phi(t))_*X) = X \circ \phi(t)$. Therefore
$\frac{d}{dt}(X \circ \phi(t)) = X \circ \phi(t) \circ V$. If you apply this to a function you get $X(V(f)\circ \phi(t))$. Thus $X \circ \phi(t)(a) = X(a) + \int X(V(f)\circ \phi(t))$

Comment: Correction to previous comment: I am considering an expansion like

$$(\phi(t,x)_{*}X)(\phi(t,q)) = \phi(t,x)_{*}[X(q)] = X(q) + \int...$$

while the Lie derivative expansion is like

$$(\phi(t,x)_{*}X)(q) = X(q) + \int...$$

The classical derivation goes on by just taking the differential of $\phi(t,x) = x + \int(V(\phi(t))$. I guess the difference lies in how you are trying to expand and whether you are interested in a particular vector at a point or a vector field.

Comment: Oh, you want to look at $\phi(t,x)_*X (\phi(t,q))$? Um, this difference is not really geometrical, since $\phi(t,x)_*X (\phi(t,q))$ is not a vector in the same tangent space as $X(q)$. But no matter, you are working on Euclidean space, so I'll assume you are using the trivial connection. But this means that, in coordinates, $\phi(t,x)_*X(\phi(t,q)) = X^i(q) \partial_i \phi^j(t,q)$ So the difference can of course be entirely estimates in terms of derivatives of $\phi$.

Comment: Yes that is what I am looking and ofcourse the integral form I get is simply by computing $\partial_i\phi^j(t,q)$. I think algebraic-wise this expression is correct but I still feel a bit itchy about this because I can not see how derivatives of $\phi(t,q)$ can account for derivatives of $X$ not appearing. I am lacking some point of view here I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment discussion, what you call $\phi_*(X(q))$ I usually think of as $\mathrm{d}\phi\cdot X(q) = X(\phi)(q)$.

That is to say, writing $\phi$ as a $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued function, what you are interested in is the (spatial) directional derivative of $\phi(t,x)$ in the direction of $X$ evaluated at the point $q$. In coordinates where $X = X^j \partial_j$ it is just

$$ (X^j \partial_j \phi^i)(t,q) $$

The reason your formula doesn't agree with those in the textbooks is because your formula is looking at something different from what the textbooks are looking at. If you are estimating something *entirely different* from what the textbooks are estimating, why should you expect that you get the same result?

(In your case you are trying to compare two vectors one based at the point $q$ and the other at $\phi(t,q)$. In the general geometric setting this doesn't make too much sense, since the two vectors live in two distinct vector spaces and cannot be compared. In your Euclidean setting you can work in canonical coordinates and ignore the coordinate ambiguity.)

In any case, what you need to estimate is the difference

$$ \partial_j\phi^i(t,q) - \delta_j^i $$

Using the partial derivatives commute, and that $\delta_j^i = \partial_j\phi^i(0,q)$ you have that

$$ \partial_j\phi^i(t,q) - \delta_j^i = \int_0^t \partial_t\partial_j\phi^i(s,q) \mathrm{d}s = \int_0^t \partial_j \left(V^i(s,\phi(s,q))\right) \mathrm{d}s $$

which is precisely what you derived. Using the chain rule we have

$$ = \int_0^t \partial_kV^i(s,\phi(s,q)) (\partial_j\phi^k(s,q) - \delta_j^k) + \partial_jV^i(s,\phi(s,q)) \mathrm{d}s $$

From this we can apply Gronwall and get

$$ |\partial_j\phi^i - \delta_j^i| \leq t \sup |DV| \exp (t \sup |DV|) $$

Comment: Yes I just realized this a fraction of a second ago :) My estimate gets a relation between $(\phi(t,x)X)_*(\phi(q))$ and X(q). The lie derivative expansion gives an estimate between  $(\phi(t,x)X)(\phi(q))$ and $X(\phi(q))$. To tie the two estimates together one needs to know how X changes which depends on DX. And ofcourse this is only valid either in coordinates or in $R^n$. It was an enlightening discussion thanks.